# Self-referential Cryptic Clue

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

```
egg-shaped type
of engine screech 
or riot scaly 
hip strangely of 
the body drunk 
hater sounds like 
angry counsellor topless 
hill amid two 
south fjords stand 
it twisted in 
the sticks
10 6 8 9 6 7 - 7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here is that

> a series of cryptic clues have been mashed together, and line breaks inserted every three words. Sorting them out, we get:
>
>  egg-shaped type of engine - ELLIPTICAL (double definition)
>  screech or riot - SCREAM (double definition, the second as in "laugh riot")
>  scaly hip strangely **of the body** - PHYSICAL (anagram of "scaly hip")
>  drunk hater sounds like angry **counsellor** - THERAPIST (anagram of "hater" + sounds like "pissed")
>  topless hill amid two south **fjords** - SOUNDS ("mound" without first letter, between "ss")
>  stand it twisted **in the sticks** - DISTANT (anagram of "stand it")
>
>  Putting the answers together, we have:
>  **elliptical** scream physical therapist sounds distant - CRYPTIC ("cry" + "PT" + "icy" sounds like the letters I C)

So the final answer is

> CRYPTIC.

Comment: Well done! I think you should replace the k with a y for the sound-alike of the last two letters.

Comment: I wondered how those things sounded alike for a minute before I got it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to use rot13, so I made my comment, er, cryptic. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yay! Someone solved it! (I was a bit sad when no one tried/succeeded back when I posted it)